# Network Scheduler Service

Tags: asp.net, windows, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am planning on a project to schedule scripts on multiple Windows and Linux servers. I'm kind of going down the path of doing this all from scratch because I have requirements which alternative software don't seem to meet (such as running tasks on completion or failure of other tasks and being able to schedule on non standard intervals).

I was thinking about having a web interface which will allow users to add/modify/delete schedules for each machine to a database. 

A windows service will then be checking the database for any jobs that need to be run at that point and connect over SSH for Linux or PowerShell for windows. 
All the scripts will write back to the database on their progress so that they can be checked by the user.

Basically I just wanted some advice from people who knows better ways or things I may need to look out for which could cause problems because I don't have much experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Scheduler has all options where you are looking for and probably more. See [Overview of Oracle Scheduler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/schedover001.htm) for some global info. It comes doen to having a central schedular database that submits jobs to remote job agents that do the work pretty much independent from the central schedular repository. It does report back status etc. when the repository is accessible after a job has finished.

It's a very powerful tool and it takes away a lot of complex tasks for you by giving a framework that you can start using right out of the box.